# Drag-bar with point that changes colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using JQuery/HTML5/CSS3, I want to create a mechanism that looks like this:

[image]

where the bar is fixed, and the red circle can be dragged from one end of it to the other. As it is dragged from left to right, I'd like the color to change from red to green (such that it's yellow when it's at the center of the bar), with the inverse occurring when dragged from right to left.

Is there something that already exists that I could modify to achieve this? If not, what's the most straight-forward way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help you:

```js
var slider = new Slider(document.getElementById('slider'), 0, 100);
slider.onChange = function(value) {
    document.getElementById('value').textContent = Math.round(value);
};
slider.setValue(25);

function Slider(container, minValue, maxValue) {
    var slider = this;
    
    ///////////
    //  DOM  //
    ///////////
    var slideGroup = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(slideGroup);
    slideGroup.style.position = 'relative';
    slideGroup.style.width =
    slideGroup.style.height =
        '100%';
    
    var slideBar = document.createElement('div');
    slideGroup.appendChild(slideBar);
    slideBar.style.position = 'absolute';
    slideBar.style.left =
    slideBar.style.right =
    slideBar.style.top =
    slideBar.style.bottom =
        Math.round(container.offsetHeight / 2 - 1) + 'px';
    slideBar.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    
    var slideButton = document.createElement('div');
    slideGroup.appendChild(slideButton);
    slideButton.style.position = 'absolute';
    slideButton.style.width =
    slideButton.style.height =
    slideButton.style.borderRadius =
        container.offsetHeight + 'px';
    
    /////////////
    //  COLOR  //
    /////////////
    var startColor = {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0};
    var midColor = {r: 255, g: 255, b: 0};
    var endColor = {r: 0, g: 255, b: 0};
    
    var colorAt = function(position) {
        if (position <= .5) {
            var r = startColor.r * (.5 - position) * 2 + midColor.r * (position - 0) * 2;
            var g = startColor.g * (.5 - position) * 2 + midColor.g * (position - 0) * 2;
            var b = startColor.b * (.5 - position) * 2 + midColor.b * (position - 0) * 2;
        } else {
            var r = midColor.r * (1 - position) * 2 + endColor.r * (position - .5) * 2;
            var g = midColor.g * (1 - position) * 2 + endColor.g * (position - .5) * 2;
            var b = midColor.b * (1 - position) * 2 + endColor.b * (position - .5) * 2;
        }
        return 'rgb('+Math.ceil(r)+', '+Math.ceil(g)+', '+Math.ceil(b)+')';
    };
    
    /////////////
    //  VALUE  //
    /////////////
    var value = null;
    
    slider.getValue = function() {
        return value;
    };
    
    slider.setValue = function(newValue) {
        value = Math.max(minValue, Math.min(maxValue, newValue));
        var position = (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
        slideButton.style.left = Math.round(position * slideBar.offsetWidth) + 'px';
        slideButton.style.backgroundColor = colorAt(position);
        if (slider.onChange) slider.onChange(value);
    };
    
    slider.setValue(minValue);
    
    /////////////
    //  MOUSE  //
    /////////////
    var sliding = false;
    var startX = 0;
    
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        if (event.target === slideButton) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sliding = true;
            startX = event.pageX;
        }
    });
    
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
        if (sliding) {
            sliding = false;
            startX = null;
        }
    });
    
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        if (sliding) {
            var newValue = value + ((event.pageX - startX) / slideBar.offsetWidth) * (maxValue - minValue);
            startX = event.pageX;
            slider.setValue(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 20px;"></div>
<div id="value" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Comment: Updated with color changes

Answer (score 0):

Check out the demo page of a plugin for range sliders here:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?peaen_tA

[image]

On inspection with Firebug, I feel confident in my assumption that the circular span element can be manipulated with jquery/javascript based on its "left" properties.

So when you find the "left" value for the middle, you can change the background color.